# Accordion HTML Mobile Resize

Tags: html, mobile, accordion

So, I've been searching all night long for the solutions and I can't find the answer for this.

Basically, I open my website on my desktop and it works perfectly! But when I open on mobile (Android), it didn't work.

[image]

The Accordion are closing the section.
You can look it by yourself here : http://blog.ahlukene.xyz

Where should I check?

Comment: The link is broken. Can you fix this?

Comment: I'm sorry, little mistakes :) updated

Comment: `The Accordion are closing the section` Do you mean that the gray area is on the rounded picture?

Comment: exactly, how do I prevent that?

Comment: Just remove the `height: 800px;` from `section` selector. http://i.stack.imgur.com/NdAsJ.png